# What's the necessary and sufficient condition for the following matrices to commute with each other?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let us first consider the following two matrices,
\begin{eqnarray}
L_1=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & e_1^T \\
\hline
e_1 & A_1
\end{array}
\right],
~~
L_2=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & e_2^T \\
\hline
e_2 & A_2
\end{array}
\right].
\end{eqnarray}
Here, $e_1=[1,0]^T$ and $e_2=[0,1]^T$. $A_1$ and $A_2$ are $2\times 2$ Hermitian matrices and can be chosen freely. My question is: What is the necessary and sufficient condition on $A_1$ and $A_2$ for $L_1$ and $L_2$ to commute?

This question can be generalized to the general setting as follows.
Consider the following $n$ matrices,
\begin{eqnarray}
L_k=\left[
\begin{array}{c|c}
0 & e_k^T \\
\hline
e_k & A_k
\end{array}
\right]
\end{eqnarray}
where $k=1,2,\cdots,n$, and $e_k$ is a $n$-dimensional vector whose $k$-th component is $1$ and all other components are $0$.$A_k$'s are Hermitian matrices and can be chosen freely as you wish. Then the question is: What is the necessary and sufficient condition on $A_k$'s for $L_k$'s to commute with each other?

I think the question is highly nontrivial. Any comment and help are welcomed.

Comment: If you do the actual multiplication few constraints become clear such as first row(resp. column) of $A_2$ is same as second row (resp. column) of $A_1$. There should be more but those are immediate.

Comment: Yes. Besides the constraint you mentioned, the other constraint is $\textrm{det}(A_1)+\textrm{det}(A_2)=1$.